# why is django appending a hash to my urls?

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have a site, on certain pages Django is appending what looks to be a hash or similar to urls, how can I disable this behavior or track down it's origin?

if I visit a url like:

```
https://mysite.com/app/
```

a hash is appended like this once the page loads:

```
https://mysite.com/app/#.VAi01PBX-uY
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like Django, which would be in the page before it all loads. This sounds like Javascript. What scripts do you load on your page?

Comment: @AndrewJohnson ended up bing an AddThis widget, ty. Post as an answer and I'll mark you as answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't sound like Django, which would be in the page before it all loads. This sounds like Javascript.

Comment: ended up bing an AddThis widget